# Is there some way to iterate an array which come in the httpResponse into a jsp

Tags: javascript, java, jpa, httpresponse

I'm sorry if you can't understand the tittle, its my first try in stackoverflow.
Context: I'm doing a web app based in JPA,JSP.
Summary I receive an array of objects which class is "pet" named "pets”, this class have name, id, and one array of pet's pictures.
I already call it with ${pets}. So, if I want a specific name, I write something like it

`<div class="container-conf ">                                                                  <div class="d-block text-center" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto" > <p class="h2 my-pets-text " id="namePet">${pets[0].name}</p> <p class="h3 my-pets-text " id="agePet">${pets[0].age}</p> </div> </div>`

It works for a specific pet, but I need to change the number of the element with a button. For example, If I click a 'next' button automatically the pet’s name changes in the next of the array.

Please I need exactly it, a way to iterate the array with a button.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know jpa,but supposed you have a pets array,and you can add a script,it could be done like this :

```html
<div class="container-conf">
    <div id="pet-container" class="d-block text-center" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto"></div>
    <button onclick="iteratePets()">NEXT PET</button>
    <script>
const pets = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "pet 1",
        age: 4,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "pet 2",
        age: 8,
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "pet 3",
        age: 1,
      },
    ];

    let count = 1;

    const iteratePets = () => {
      document.getElementById(
        "pet-container"
      ).innerHTML = `<p>${pets[count].name}</p>`;
      pets.length < count + 2 ? (count = 0) : count++;
    };

    window.onload = () => {
      document.getElementById(
        "pet-container"
      ).innerHTML = `<p>${pets[0].name}</p>`;
    };
    </script>
</div>
```